# Sql Calculate Average

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to calculate the average number of pests in a Town who are using the same Variety of crops..

```
DistrictName    | TownName           | CropName    |Pests   
Rawalpindi      | pindi              | CIM 506     | 3.3     
Rawalpindi      | pindi              | CIM 506     | 3.8     
Rawalpindi      | Muree              | CIM 506     | 3.5
```

But this query keeps on giving me the syntax error i.e Invalid Column name `PestPopulation1` where as i thoroughly checked the spellings of my column name...`PestPopuplation` is of `varchar(max)`type

Following is my query

```
SELECT T.DistrictName, T.TownName, T.VarietyOfCrop, avg(T.PestPopulation1)
FROM (
    SELECT DistrictName, TownName,VarietyOfCrop, cast(PestPopulation1 as float) as Pests
    FROM FinalTable2
) as T
group by T.DistrictName, T.TownName, T.VarietyOfCrop
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned, the problem is that you refer to a column that's not available in that scope.

Altogether there's not even a good reason to use such a contrived query. This should work just as well, and is more readable:

```
SELECT T.DistrictName, T.TownName, T.VarietyOfCrop, avg(cast(T.Pests as float))
FROM FinalTable2 T
group by T.DistrictName, T.TownName, T.VarietyOfCrop
```

Comment: Error converting data type nvarchar to float.   it give me this error ...my Pest column in of varchar max

Answer (score 4):

The reason this gives you an error is because you gave the expression `cast(PestPopulation1 as float)` an alias `Pests`.

You should use that alias in your outer query, like this:

```
SELECT T.DistrictName, T.TownName, T.VarietyOfCrop, avg(T.Pests)
FROM (
    SELECT DistrictName, TownName,VarietyOfCrop, cast(PestPopulation1 as float) as Pests
    FROM FinalTable2
) as T
group by T.DistrictName, T.TownName, T.VarietyOfCrop
```

You should be able to simplify this query by pushing the `cast` into `avg`, like this:

```
SELECT
    DistrictName
,   TownName
,   VarietyOfCrop
,   avg(convert(float, PestPopulation1)) as avg_pests
FROM FinalTable2
group by T.DistrictName, T.TownName, T.VarietyOfCrop
```

> Error converting data type `nvarchar` to `float`. My `PestPopulation1` column in of `varchar(max)`.

You need to use `CONVERT` instead of `CAST` (see above).

Comment: Error converting data type nvarchar to float. it give me this error ...my Pest column in of varchar max –

Comment: @user1056466 Use `convert` instead of `cast` then.

Comment: @user1056466 You didn't do something correctly then: here's a [link to a demo on sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/20b18/6), `varchar(max)` can be converted to `float` if it holds a value that can be converted.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT T.DistrictName, T.TownName, T.VarietyOfCrop, avg(T.PestPopulation1)
FROM (
    SELECT DistrictName, TownName,VarietyOfCrop, cast(Pests as float) as PestPopulation1 
    FROM FinalTable2
) as T
group by T.DistrictName, T.TownName, T.VarietyOfCrop
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just (with CONVERT instead of CAST):

```
SELECT DistrictName, TownName,VarietyOfCrop, AVG(CONVERT(float, PestPopulation1)) as Pests
FROM FinalTable2
GROUP BY DistrictName, TownName,VarietyOfCrop
```

The error in your query is that you are referencing a column that the table T has not. The derived table T has columns DistrictName, TownName,VarietyOfCrop and Pests, and you are referencing the column PestPopulation1 that doesn't exists there.

Comment: Error converting data type nvarchar to float. it give me this error ...my Pest column in of varchar max –

Comment: @user1056466 Try this, with CONVERT instead of CAST

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong column name, the alias for *PestPopulation1* is *Pests* in your subquery, please find the corrected query:

```
SELECT T.DistrictName, T.TownName, T.VarietyOfCrop, avg(T.Pests)  
FROM (  
SELECT DistrictName, TownName,VarietyOfCrop, cast(PestPopulation1 as float) as Pests  
FROM FinalTable2
) as T  
group by T.DistrictName, T.TownName, T.VarietyOfCrop
```